# jQuery Getting Element Class as Specified in CSS

Tags: jquery, class

I know that Attr gets the exact class of an element. Is there a way to get the element exact class as defined in CSS?
For example an element may have class "title" but be defined in CSS as a descendant selector, something like: .other-list .title {}
I need something to get that exact class value. You can see here the full example:
http://jsfiddle.net/2TMgQ/2/

On click both elements have class "title" but are defined in CSS as 2 different elements.
Thank you

Comment: You *can* do this, but do you **need** to?  It's possible, Firebug Lite does this, but it isn't pretty: http://fbug.googlecode.com/svn/lite/branches/firebug1.4/content/firebug/css.js

Comment: YEap, I need to. Indeed Firebug does it. I do not think that i will be able to understand the FireBug code. That was the first place i had looked in to, I thought that there is an easier way... how about this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/cssRule.selectorText

Comment: Indeed they are using "selectorText", just looked again to their code. Can't figure it out how, the code is to big to understand it

Comment: @Mircea - Let me put it this way...the Firebug guys are good, and they wouldn't do it a way that's more complicated that was required (*for them*).  You can strip from their implementation because you don't need *all* that functionality, but just finding the rules isn't easy.  For example what if 10 rules applied to your element, then what? Which do you use?  It could always be a list, what if your example was this instead? http://jsfiddle.net/2TMgQ/9/

Comment: @Nick, I an sure that FireBug guys are top. In their code is much functionality I do not need. I nyour example I would take .links-list .title and .other-list .title for second

Comment: @Mircea - Right...but how would the *code* know which ones you wanted? Why those and not the others? I ask because you'll have to turn whatever reasoning you have into code/logic that always works.

Comment: Hmmm, good question. I do believe that I need the most specific selector from an element THAT is also defined in the external CSS. Hard thing to do, I was hoping that jQuery have something for this

Comment: I once tried to get jQuery to do the dishes $("plates","glasses").wash();

Comment: @Marko - Why were the plates *in* the glasses? Was it really big glasses or really little plates?

Comment: Crap so that's why it didn't work, I'm gonna try $("plates,glasses").wash(); My mother will be proud!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you all CSS styles that apply to the element. It uses jQuery's `is` function to check if a CSS rule selector applies to a given element. Iterate through all stylesheets in `document.styleSheets`, and through all `cssRules` in each stylesheet, and check if `selectorText` matches the element. In pseudocode:

```
given::element

matchedRules = []

for styleSheet in document.styleSheets
    for rule in styleSheet.cssRules
        if element.is(rule.selectorText)
            matchedRules.push(rule.selectorText)

return matchedRules;
```

In code:

```
function getCSSRules(element) {
    element = $(element);

    var styleSheets = document.styleSheets;
    var matchedRules = [], rules, rule;

    for(var i = 0; i < styleSheets.length; i++) {
        rules = styleSheets[i].cssRules;

        for(var j = 0; j < rules.length; j++) {
            rule = rules[j];
            if(element.is(rule.selectorText)) {
               matchedRules.push(rule.selectorText);
            }
        }
    }

    return matchedRules;
}
```

This should return all rules that apply to the element. For your [first example](http://jsfiddle.net/2TMgQ/2/), it returns:

```
[".links-list .title"]
```

For Nick's [extended example](http://jsfiddle.net/2TMgQ/9/), it returns:

```
[".links-list .title", ".title", "a", "li a"]
```

How you define *specificity* and how to decide what to filter out from this list is upto you.

Comment: This is the exact result I need. Let me try it out.

Comment: Thanx, this is getting the exact selectors as Firebug.

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to parent - child selectors then the syntax would be something like:

```
$(".other-list > .title")
```

Have a look at http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Comment: He wants to GET the parent class

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could help

[CSS parser/abstracter? How to convert stylesheet into object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2226869/css-parser-abstracter-how-to-convert-stylesheet-into-object)