# How can I get width of div, which is written in CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want width of a div element which is specified by developer.
Means if you write `$('body').width()`, it will provide you width in **px** , whether you have specified it or not.

I need width of div specified in CSS/JavaScript but not which is calculated by jQuery (which was not actually specified but was inherited).

If not width is specified then I need to know.

Comment: @Bruno , but if I haven't specified any width for body , its taking width of browser.I need to know if width is written for element (here body) or its inherited.

Comment: @Bruno,  You will improve your reputation faster if you write answers to questions.

Comment: Have you tried solving the problem?

Comment: @Yoshi , yes .But just not understanding if width is applied by css or  its inherited.

Comment: sorry about that. Will look for the real answer :(

Comment: np @Bruno , I me looking for same.And I may be new at stack but not in    html. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code below will loop through all stylesheets as well as the matching element's style property. This function will return an array of widths.

```
function getCSSWidths( id ) {

    var stylesheets = document.styleSheets;
    var widths = [];
    var styleWidth;

    // loop through each stylesheet
    $.each( stylesheets, function( i, sheet ) {

        var len = ( sheet.rules.length || sheet.cssRules.length );
        var rules = sheet.rules || sheet.cssRules;

        // loop through rules
        for (var i=0; i < len; i++) {

            var rule = rules[i];

            // if width is specified in css add to widths array
            if (rule.selectorText.toLowerCase() == "#" + id.toLowerCase() ) {
                widths.push( rule.style.getPropertyValue("width"));
            }
        }
    });

    var el = document.getElementById( id );

    // get width specified in the html style attribute
    if( el && el.style && el.style.width ) {
        widths.push( el.style.width );
    }

    return widths;
}

getCSSWidths( "test" );
```

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/bruno/MTAu9/5/)

There is one issue that I can see though as multiple selectors can be specified in the selectorText i.e.

```
#id1, #id2, .class1 {
    // properties
}
```

In these cases the id passed in as an argument will not match the selectorText property. Maybe someone can come up with a regex expression that will match the specified id :)

Comment: This is the closest answer.but still not exact... :-)

Answer (score 2):

```
<style type="text/css">
    .largeField {
        width: 65%;
    }
</style>
<script>
    var rules = document.styleSheets[0].rules || document.styleSheets[0].cssRules;
    for (var i=0; rules.length; i++) {
        var rule = rules[i];
        if (rule.selectorText.toLowerCase() == ".largefield") {
            alert(rule.style.getPropertyValue("width"));
        }
    }
</script>
```

Possibly duplicate with [get CSS rule's percentage value in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/744319/get-css-rules-percentage-value-in-jquery) or [Getting values of global stylesheet in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7131462/getting-values-of-global-stylesheet-in-jquery/7132264#7132264)

Answer (score 1):

For the Javascript specified width, you can try this:

`document.getElementById("myDivElement").style.width`

If the above returns an empty string, it means it has not been specified by Javascript.

As for rules specified through CSS, find the class name(s) of the element and then the rules specified for that class:

`var className = document.getElementById("myDivElement").className;`

var cssWidth = getWidthFromClassname(className);

Now you need to define `getWidthFromClassname`:

```
function getWidthFromClassname(className)
{
    var reqWidth;
    var classes = document.styleSheets[0].rules || document.styleSheets[0].cssRules
    for(var x=0;x<classes.length;x++) {
        if(classes[x].selectorText==className) {
             reqWidth = classes[x].style.getPropertyValue("width");
             break;
        }
    }

    return reqWidth;
}
```

Comment: That complicates things. Perhaps you can iterate parent elements and find their width/css rule and compare with the offsetWidth of the element to determine whether its width is inherited or not(if a CSS rule specified width is equal to the offsetWidth, you can conclude that the width is inherited).

Comment: I am doing same but process is very slow and not fullproof, also unoptimised.

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById('divid').style.width
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `clientWidth` property, it calculates the actual width of the element, regardless if set through CSS or if it's the natural flow of the document:

```
document.getElementById('divId').clientWidth
```

If you want the full content width with margins/paddings/border you can use `offsetWidth`:

```
document.getElementById('divId').offsetWidth
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.offsetWidth
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.clientWidth