# Why isn't this function returning a css rule?

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, dom

I'm trying to write some helper functions so I can edit a css class through javascript. Here is what I have, but I don't understand why it keeps returning "undefined". Im using chrome for testing.

```
    function getRule(name, doDelete) { //takes a rule name and boolean

    if(document.styleSheets) { //check if there are stylesheets

        for(var i = 0; i < document.styleSheets.length; i++) { //loop through style sheets

            var currentSheet = document.styleSheets[i];
            if(currentSheet.cssRules) { //if the sheet has rules

                for(var h = 0; h < currentSheet.cssRules.length; h++) { //loop through css rules

                    var currentRule = currentSheet.cssRules[h];
                    if(currentRule.selectorText == name) { //if rule name is equal to the name given

                        return currentRule; //return the css rule

                    }

                }

            }

        }

    }

}
```

css being used:

```
    .menuopen {

    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
    width: 960px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: 3b7ea8;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 2px 5px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    -webkit-animation-name: dropAnimation;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 2s;

    }
```

Comment: How are you searching for the rule? I just did a Fiddle and your code seems to work! http://jsfiddle.net/kA24S/2/

Comment: Really? I'm using it in Chrome and typed getRule(".dropmenu") and it doesn't work. Maybe it's just chrome?

Comment: I am also using Chrome. Can I see the CSS you're using?

Comment: the name was changed to "menuopen" recently just to let you know it's not a mistake.

Comment: The reason why I'm struggling is because I can't seem to reproduce your problem; your code seems to work perfectly fine. Take a look at this new jsFiddle I made. Review the code and tell me if this is what you're looking for: http://jsfiddle.net/GRFrr/1/

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16965515/how-to-get-a-style-attribute-from-a-css-class-by-javascript-jquery/16966533#16966533) might be helpful

Answer (score 1):

Could one of these issues be the problem?
    [document.styleSheets[n].cssRules null when page accessed locally](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=143626&q=document.stylesheets&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Iteration%20ReleaseBlock%20Cr%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified)
    [cssRules is null for CSSStyleSheets from other domains](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=224303&q=document.stylesheets&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Iteration%20ReleaseBlock%20Cr%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified)
    [Regression: cssRules null when stylesheets loaded from local disk](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=49001&q=document.stylesheets&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Iteration%20ReleaseBlock%20Cr%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modifiedhttps://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=49001&q=document.stylesheets&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Iteration%20ReleaseBlock%20Cr%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified)
These issues occur based on how your stylesheets are included and how you load your page (from disk or from a server).