# Obtain width from CSS class before element appended?

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js

I need the width of the parent `div` for calculations within the child `div`, but neither have been appended yet in the D3 chain. How can I extract the width out of e.g.

```
.element {
    width: 120px;
    height: 200px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 12px rgba(0,255,255,0.5);
    border: 1px solid rgba(127,255,255,0.25);
    text-align: center;
    cursor: default;
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason you can't do the calculation in between the appending of the parent and the child divs?

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/16965515

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`getComputedStyle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.getComputedStyle) and a temporary DOM element with the class name to read the applied CSS.

```
var el = document.createElement("div");
el.className = "element";
document.body.appendChild(el);
var elementWidth = getComputedStyle(el, null).width;
document.body.removeChild(el);
```

This code will create a new `div` element with the class of `element`, add it to the `body`, read the applied CSS `width` setting it to the variable `elementWidth`, and remove the temporary element from the DOM.

Alternatively, you can do this with jQuery.

```
var el = $("div").addClass("element").appendTo("body");
var elementWidth = el.css("width");
el.remove();
```

Comment: Is there a reason you chose not to use d3 for the DOM manipulation?

Comment: @MikePrecup D3 isn't very helpful for single element manipulation like this. Vanila JS is faster.

Comment: The outer element and inner div with its d3 svg are placed within a THREE.CSS3DObject object to be rendered in a Three.js canvas with a THREE.CSS3DRenderer() ... so I'm thinking that the element actually gets a width about 10 miles down the pike from where I need it for the x attr of a rect within the svg. Should have mentioned that. Creating and destroying works perfectly - thanks for that ..... did more googling on reading css class with js - nasty stuff!

Comment: looking at Mike's comment .... at the moment I am doing a lot of create elements before the d3 statement to add svg data. Is Mike saying that I could do all of this within a  d3.select("body) .... statement and that the parent is passed on to each .append('child') so that all parent attributes including width are available to each child as it is created?

Comment: @MicC I think Mike was asking why I didn't use D3 to add the temporary element and suggesting that you could calculate the width of the parent element before appending the child.