# Check whether a CSS class has a particular attribute or not

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

It might be repeated question but still need of time is that I want a solution.
I am new to CSS and jQuery, so here is what I am looking for.
I have a css like this

```
.my-selector { 
    background-size: cover;
    something-here1 : 2;
}
```

Now I want to check whether this `my-selector` has `backgroud-size` as one of the elements or not, if it has then I want to add new element in same selector.
This I want to do in JavaScript or using jQuery

Answer (score 0):

btw: jQuery IS javascript.

```
if (!$(this).hasClass("my-selector")) {
   //rlemons post [link below] deals with this
}
```

[look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16965515/how-to-get-a-style-attribute-from-a-css-class-by-javascript-jquery) for rlemon's anwer for the this part