# How to get a style attributes from a CSS class if there are more than two CSS classes?

Tags: javascript

**.css**

```
.Fchkbox, .Fchkbox-lg {
   position: absolute;
   display: block;
   margin-top: 10px;
}
```

Here I am getting style attribute value if

```
1>getStyleRuleValue("margin-top",".Fchkbox");
  result:-10px;

2>getStyleRuleValue("margin-top", ".Fchkbox-lg");
```

So here I am not getting the result as 10px....why? How can I resolve this?

Comment: Please, consider rewriting your question, which is unreadable at the moment.

Comment: getStyleRuleValue("margin-top", ".Fchkbox-lg" document.styleSheets[2]);

Comment: What does getStyleRuleValue do. We have no insight of this method...

Comment: @AlbertVanHalen  for you read rlemon answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16965515/how-to-get-a-style-attribute-from-a-css-class-by-javascript-jquery

Comment: sorry sir .!this is my first time......,i stuck while writing the question in correct format.

Comment: You should split the stylerule on comma including whitespace.
`rule.selectorText.split(/\,\s?/)`

The two selectors in your stylerule are put into an array and checked against the second argument of the method call.
' .Fchkbox-lg' is put into the array (note  the leading space!) which is not the same as '.Fchkbox-lg'; therefore returning null.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the method described in this article : [How to get a style attribute from a CSS class by javascript/jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16965515/how-to-get-a-style-attribute-from-a-css-class-by-javascript-jquery) the code should be tweaked.
The stylerule is split on a comma into an array of different selectors.
You should split on comma including whitespace.
`rule.selectorText.split(/,\s?/)`