# Replace the CSS class in HTML element with its CSS properties in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to get the HTML page's source code using JavaScript (kind of like screenshot). And for styling, I am using external CSS. However, when I get the HTML source code, the styling won't be applied because I won't be able to get the CSS properties for the elements.

So, I am wondering if I can replace the CSS class name with actual CSS properties defined in that class. e.g.

for the HTML element,

```
<div class="exampleClass"><div>
```

And CSS,

```
.exampleClass {
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
}
```

Then the extracted source code using Javascript will be

```
<div style="background-color:#FFFFFF;"><div>
```

How can I do this thing in JavaScript?
Thanks

Comment: This might help you... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/324486/how-do-you-read-css-rule-values-with-javascript

Comment: Maybe its possible to hack something but to get the full "cascading" nature of css this would be fairly tricky.  Why don't you just pull down the stylesheets too?

Comment: you will still be missing:  pseudo classes, `@media`, `@print`,, `@import`, `@keyframes` , .... , you 'd better import the whole style sheet and store it in `<style>`tag ...

Comment: @G-Cyr, That sounds like a better option

Answer (score 1):

```css
function getCSSPropertiesBySelector(selector) {
    return [...document.styleSheets].map(stylesheet => {
        var g = [...stylesheet.cssRules].find(rule => rule.selectorText === selector);
        if (g) {
            return g.style.cssText;
        }
    }).find(r => r);
}
```

Mostly based off of https://stackoverflow.com/a/16966533/1799147

```js
getCSSPropertiesBySelector('.logo')
//"display: block; grid-area: I / I / I / I; width: 200px; height: 44px; margin-right: 24px;"
```

There's probably better ways to do this but it gets the job done. It won't work if there's a duplicate class in this example, you'd probably want it to be changed to append to the properties if you had the same class in another stylesheet

Answer (score 0):

You can assign the desired class to the tag HTML in javascript. For example:

```
const div = document.createElement('div');
div.className = 'exampleClass';
document.body.appendChild(div);
```

Or

```
div.classList.add('exampleClass');
```