# Get CSS properties in JS by css class name

Tags: javascript, css

How do I get the CSS properties of an element with js? Let say I have the following

```css
.btn {
  background-color: green;
}

.navbtn {
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

and

```html
<button id='mybtn' class='btn navbtn' onclick='alert("hi")'>Click me</button>
```

Then, I want to extract the CSS properties of the element `mybtn`. If I do

```js
window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById('mybtn'))
```

it returns a CSSStyleDeclaration which contains all CSS properties, even those I didn't set. However, what I want is an object (or whatever) that contains

```css
{
  background-color: green;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

and everything else will consider as 'default'.

So my question is:

1. Is there such function or library that does the job?
2. If not, is it possible to get the CSS properties given the class name (like `getProperties('btn')` returns `{ background-color: green; }`)

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is the answer for your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16966533/1789796

Comment: @empiric Not really. I do not know which properties were modified. So I can't do `window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById('mybtn')).fontSize` because I didn't know `fontSize` was modified.

Answer (score -2):

So simple as this code :

```
let background = document.querySelector('.btn').style.backgroundColor;
console.log(backround);
```

Comment: The reads the inline style of a specific property. The question is looking for all the properties set, but not through inline style